# jquery switching from "bind-click" to "...load right away?"

Tags: jquery

So i have some jquery, currently it is activated by clicking on a link and it changes the link from just text to opening up a google map view embedded in the web page - I want to eliminate the need to click and just want the map to load

I didnt write the template and Imma jquery noob, will someone hold my hand for a moment please?

```
        $(".openGoogleMap").bind('click', function() {
            if(self.curPageview !== null && self.curPageview !== undefined){
                self.curPageview.find("#map_canvas").each(function (){
                    $(this).addClass("openMap");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        try{
                            if(!self.mapLoad) { map_initialize(); self.mapLoad = true; } 
                        } catch (e) {
                            $(this).html($(this).data("con"));          
                        }   
                        mapResizer();

                        self.curPageview.find(".m-Scrollbar").each(             
                          function(){   
                            var selg = $(this);             
                            if(selg.data('added')){ 
                                try{    selg.mCustomScrollbar("update");    } catch (e) { }                         
                            }
                        });

                    },700); 
                });
            }
        });
```

Currently, the .bind('click is what allows me to click the text to load the map in its place...I just want the map to load when its in view or whenever really (the template is kinda funky, its a one pager, with a ton of javascript funkyness)

I have tried changing 'click' to 'load' and 'inview' (guess its a separate script?) but now im thinking that .bind might be the problem

Comment: Unless you're using an older version of jQuery, consider to use on() instead.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be:

```
$(".openGoogleMap").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to eliminate the requirement for the click event, and instead just execute the contained code as soon as possible. One way you could achieve this is binding it to the document's "ready" event rather than .openGoogleMap's "click" event. Just swapping a few things in the first line:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if(self.curPageview !== null && self.curPageview !== undefined){
        self.curPageview.find("#map_canvas").each(function (){
            $(this).addClass("openMap");
            setTimeout(function(){
                try{
                    if(!self.mapLoad) { map_initialize(); self.mapLoad = true; } 
                } catch (e) {
                    $(this).html($(this).data("con"));          
                }   
                mapResizer();

                self.curPageview.find(".m-Scrollbar").each(             
                  function(){   
                    var selg = $(this);             
                    if(selg.data('added')){ 
                        try{    selg.mCustomScrollbar("update");    } catch (e) { }                         
                    }
                });

            },700); 
        });
    }
});
```

Now the code will fire as soon as the document loads - though I can't be positive this will work, as I don't know how this fits in with the rest of the code in the plugin; there might be dependencies I didn't account for. (On a slightly related note though, ".bind()" is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery, so try avoiding using it if you're not using an older version.)

Anyways, hope this helps! Let me know if it worked - if not I'd be happy to help further.